# Evaluate the integral $PV\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x^2+2x+2)}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Using the Cauchy Integral Principal to evaluate:

$$PV\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x^2+2x+2)}dx$$

I know this integral has a pole at $x=i$, $x = -1-i$ and $x = -1+i$. Can someone please show me how to use Cauchy Principal value to evaluate this integral ?

Comment: Cauchy Principal value is used to assign values to improper integrals which would otherwise be undefined. This integral very much exist: the integrand has no singularities on $(-\infty,\infty)$ and the falloff is $\frac{1}{x^4}$ so the integral has a finite value.

Comment: You can evaluate it using contour integration. Integrate over $[-R,R]$ and then over a semi-circle in the upper half-plane from $R$ to $-R$. This latter integral falls off as $\frac{1}{R^4}\times R =\frac{1}{R^3}$ by the [ML-inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma). Take $R\to\infty$ and use the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). There are only two poles inside this contour $i$ and $-1+i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C_R$ denote the closed semi-circle of radius $R$ centered at $z=0$ in the lower-half plane oriented in anti-clockwise fashion.
$$
\int_{C_R}{dz\over(z^2+1)(z^2+2z+2)}=\\\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{iRe^{it}dt\over(R^2e^{2it}+1)(R^2e^{2it}+2Re^{it}+2)}+\int_{R}^{-R}{dx\over(x^2+1)(x^2+2x+1)}
$$
Now $|R^2e^{2it}+1|=R^2|e^{2it}+R^{-2}|>{R^2\over2}$ for large enough $R$.

Simliarly,
$|R^2e^{2it}+2Re^{it}+2|>{R^2\over2}$ for large enough $R$.

So for large enough $R$, the absolute value of the integrand in the first integral is less than ${4\over R^3}$.
$$
\therefore\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R}{dz\over(z^2+1)(z^2+2z+2)}=\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}{dx\over(x^2+1)(x^2+2x+1)}
$$ 
As *Winther* notes Cauchy principal value is redundant here. Using residue theorem we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{dx\over(x^2+1)(x^2+2x+1)}=-2\pi i\left[\text{Res}_{-1-i}\left({1\over(z^2+1)(z^2+2z+2)}\right)+\text{Res}_{-i}\left({1\over(z^2+1)(z^2+2z+2)}\right)\right]=-2\pi i{1\over(z^2+1)(z+1-i)}\Big{|}_{z=-1-i}-2\pi i{1\over(z-i)(z^2+2z+2)}\Big{|}_{z=-i}\\
={2\pi\over5}
$$

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of using the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) here, because the function 
$$
f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2+1)(z^2+2z+2)}
$$ is defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ (its denominator is nowhere vanishing on $\mathbb{R}$). You should use the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) instead. 
Notice first that $f$ has four simple poles:
$$
-i,\, i,\, -1-i,\, -1+i.
$$
Given $R>\sqrt2$, we denote by $\Delta(R)$ the bounded region of $\mathbb{C}$ whose boundary consists of the segment $[-R,R]$, and the upper half circle centered at the origin with radius $R$.

Thanks to the Residue Theorem, we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{\Delta(R)}f(z)\,dz&=&2\pi i[\mathrm{Res}(f,i)+\mathrm{Res}(f,-1+i)]=2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{2i(i^2+2i+2)}+\frac{1}{[(-1+i)^2+1][2(-1+i+1)]}\right]\\
&=&2\pi \left[\frac{1}{2(1+2i)}+\frac{1}{2(1-2i)}\right]=\frac{2\pi}{5}.
\end{eqnarray}
Now, notice that
$$
\int_{\Delta(R)}f(z)\,dz=\int_{-R}^Rf(x)\,dx+i\int_0^\pi Re^{it}f(Re^{it})\,dt,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty}\left|i\int_0^\pi Re^{it}f(Re^{it})\,dt\right|\le \lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{\pi R}{(R^2-1)(R^2-2R-2)}=0,
$$
and therefore
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x^2+2x+2)}\,dx=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^Rf(x)\,dx=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\Delta(R)}f(z)\,dz=\frac{2\pi}{5}.
$$